# Trying to get sum of col[A] if col[B] is in specific range

Tags: r

I'm trying to get `sum` of percentages, which are in specific range of wages.

I have table of `wop` which means 'wages of people'. It's like this

```
wage   percentage
2      0.1
3      0.1
3.4    0.01
3.5    0.12
4      0.01
5      0.02
6.3    0.1
7      0.2
9      0.11
12     0.12
.
.
.
```

You can see this table is ordered according to `wage`.
I'm trying to sum all the percentages if the wage ids in the range of
`[middle wage*0.5  <  x  <= middle wage*1.5]`
`middle wage` means that if we range the rows ordered by wage, and if the accumulated sum of percentage is 'closest to but smaller than 0.5', that wage is called `middle wage`.

I did like this

```
wop$per <- cumsum(wop&percentage)
```

And found  `[which.min(wop$per-0.5 < 0) - 1]` gives me the 'middle wage'.

So I continued to make function like this

```
mid <- function(x){
  if(x$wage <= x[which.min(wop$per-0.5 < 0) - 1 , 1]*1.5 &
      x$wage > x[which.min(wop$per-0.5 < 0) - 1 , 1]*0.5) {
    a <- sum(x$percentage)
  }
  return(a)
}
```

but this code continues to show 'error'.

Please help... how to solve this problem.

Comment: By range do you mean arrange? Could you show what the expected output would look like?

Comment: Do you mean median with middle wage? If so, sum(wop$percentage[wop$wage>0.5*median(wop$wage) | wop$wage<1.5*median(wop$wage)])

Comment: @NelsonGon  I mean 'range' :) What Rui showed seems perfectly right! thanks

Comment: @00schneider Yes median :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a vectorized way of doing what the question asks for.

```
mid<- function(DF){
  DF <- DF[order(DF[['wage']]), ]
  y <- cumsum(DF[['percentage']])
  i <- which.max(y[y < 0.5])
  inx <- DF[i, 'wage']*0.5 < DF[['wage']] & DF[['wage']] < DF[i, 'wage']*1.5
  sum(DF[inx, 'percentage'])
}  

mid(wop)
#[1] 0.57
```

**Data.**

```
wop <- read.table(text = "
wage   percentage
2      0.1
3      0.1
3.4    0.01
3.5    0.12
4      0.01
5      0.02
6.3    0.1
7      0.2
9      0.11
12     0.12
", header = TRUE)
```